# small margin / gap at the top of document

Tags: css

I have come across this before a while back and forgotten what the solution was.
I have a small gap at the very top of my document, maybe 5/10px?

I think you will know what I am talking about, how do i get rid of this?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your CSS file add this:

```
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: Perfect, knew it was something simple!