# Unwanted space before page-header in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just starting with Bootstrap and I am trying to make the `page-header` align to the top of page with no space between the start of header and web page (just like the black StackOverflow header on this page).

The code for the same is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" ></link>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-header" style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#009688;margin-top:0px">
      <h1 style="text-align:center" >Welcome to USICT ATTENDANCE RECORD</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <p style="padding:1em 2em 1sem 2em">The table lists the name of people
          studying in USICT along with their attendance in each subject.
      </p>
      <br/>
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Attendance(in %)</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Rahul</td>
            <td>Tyagi</td>
            <td>rahul.1992.tyagi@gmail.com</td>
            <td>70</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However I am getting a space between header and address bar of browser as shown in picture below:

[image: Gap above the green bar]

I have tried setting

```
margin-top:0px;
```

and

```
position:absolute;
top:0px;
```

both don't work.

Comment: Try the solution from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4501007/small-margin-gap-at-the-top-of-document).

Comment: Try to apply the `margin` and `padding` rules to `h1` rather than `header`. Or just debug the box models of each element with your browser tools.

Comment: @Xufox yeah the h1 ws causing problems since bootstrap styles the headings with a default margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h1` has a margin that exceeds the green bar.

Apply the following styles:

```
<div class="page-header" style="color:#FFFFFF;background-color:#009688;padding:9px 4px;margin-top:0;">
```

```
<h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">Welcome to USICT ATTENDANCE RECORD</h1>
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cptetmhL/1/).

Answer (score 1):

I Found out the culprit actually it was the h1 which was causing problems.

Since bootstrap applies default margins to h1,h2,h3 ...etc .

So I had to set both the margin of page-header as well as h1 to zero

which solved the problem.

Thank you for the slight hint about h1 from Xufox

Answer (score 1):

Every heading tag such as h1, h2, h3 etc has its own margin thats why you get a white space.Before style your markup you should initializing some style example: tag , ,  so that you do get twitter bootstrap's own style.This is good practicing of style from markup.

Comment: Your example is not very clear elaborate more maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put a container-fluid and then a row and your page-header ?

Like this :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="page-header">blabla</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because i didn't want to use it